# How to measure JavaScript performance (aside from page load time)

Tags: javascript, performance, cpu

There seem to be a lot of tools to check how much time it takes to *load* a specific script, but what about performance impact on the user's machine? Does anyone know of any tools to see the CPU demands of a specific script, especially on mobile?

As I write apps, I feel like I'm trying my best to cut down on unnecessary logic, but I have a hard time knowing how I'm doing — and whether the end user's experience will be smooth — with no CPU benchmarks or guidelines.

Comment: A better approach would be to actually run the app and see where the experience is smooth and where it is not, then focus on those areas.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. But this means getting access to a slower computer, multiple older-phones etc. Or is there a way to emulate slower machines/phones?

Answer (score 2):

There are some tools out there but if you are using chrome you already have a great one installed:
https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/timeline

Comment: Yes, thanks! I've been using timeline to analyze loading, but I just didn't realize you could hit record for events at any time.

Comment: Adding to that, do you know how CPU time translates into performance on slower machines? I'm assuming chrome is telling me that it took _my_ computer that amount of CPU time to run the script. How does this translate to how much CPU time a phone, say, would take? Or do I just have to test on other devices and see?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use profiling browser tools (like in Firefox right click-> Inspect element and choose performance tab).

Or you can measure your functions performance by using [High Resolution Time API](http://www.w3.org/TR/hr-time/)